# Cannot create an instance of GoogleMaps

Tags: google-maps, swift3, core-location

I'm trying to integrate Core Location w/ Google Maps, but the program keeps crashing and the debugger isn't providing any insight into what I'm doing wrong.  I'm configuring the map when I'm transitioning from one view to another, but it crashes before the transition.  I'm using a custom transition  (presentation controller). I don't think this is the issue, but wanted to mention it just in case.

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager.distanceFilter = 50
            locationManager.delegate = self
            let defaultLocation = CLLocation(latitude: -33.869405, longitude: 151.199)

            print(popUpView2.bounds)  //(0.0, 0.0, 290.0, 410.0)

            let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: defaultLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: defaultLocation.coordinate.longitude, zoom: zoomLevel)
            mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: popUpView2.bounds, camera: camera)  // **Program Crashes Here**
            mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
            mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true

            popUpView2.addSubview(mapView)
            mapView.mapType = GMSMapViewType.terrain
            mapView.isHidden = true

            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Comment: add some crash details.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a Container View and simply change:

```
popUpView2.addSubview(mapView)
```

to:

```
mapContainerView.addSubview(mapView)
```

I did this in Interface Builder and set the appropriate constraints.